# How would I use an autogenerated primary key which is also a foreign key of another table to insert data using JPA?

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, entity, one-to-one, shared-primary-key

I have two tables. The structure is

**Personal table**
Auto Id Number, int, Primary Key |
Name, Varchar |
Age, int |

**Demographic table**
Auto id number, int, foreign key |
Address, varchar |

I've created entity classes as below:

**PersonalEntity.class**

```
@Entity
@Table("Personal")
public class PersonalEntity {

@Id
@Column(name="Auto Id Number")   
private int id;

@Column(name="Name")
private String name;

@Column(name="Age")
private int age;

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private DemographicEntity de;
```

**DemographicEntity.class**

```
@Id
@Column(name="Auto Id Number")   
private int id;

@Column(name="Address") 
private String address;
```

**Dao Class**

```
@Transactional
public PersonalEntity add(PersonalEntity pe, DemographicEntity de){
     pe.setDe(de);
     entitymanager.persist(pe);
     return pe;
}
```

I am using jpa with Microsoft SQL. I want to insert data into the Personal table first and the db will auto generate a primary key. That primary key is the foreign key of Demographic table. When I called the `persist()` I am getting the error

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint. could
> not execute statement; contraint(null)

What am I doing wrong here? I want to insert data in the personal table and using the auto generated key, I want to insert data in the demographic table

Answer (score 0):

You have to set optional=false on the OneToOne mapping to tell Hibernate that the FK may not be null

```
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, optional=false)
```

Comment: Still, it says > not-null property references a null or transient value

Comment: Where do you set the attribute de?

Comment: I've added the Dao method where I set the data to persist

Comment: Where does de come from and where is the transaction?

Comment: @Transaction is used in the add method. De is passed as argument

Comment: And is de a new object or an existing entity?